# Trying to get some information from different tables - comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to obtain the lowest price for a product from a table of product prices per store. Also, i want to validate if the amount entered by the user exist in the STOCK table as well.

Take note:

> A user has an address and this address is associated with a zipcode.
>
> The user will be able to choose different products from table
>   "Products", these products exist (or not) in different supermarkets
>   and the supermarkets have different zipcodes (in my model zipcodes
>   from table **address** and table **market** are the same).
>
> Inside Products table there are multiple items that belong to
>   different supermarkets and they have different prices. I only want to
>   insert inside LIST table those items that have the lowest price
>   compared to other supermarkets. If an item has the lowest price but
>   the zipcode of the supermarket does not math to the zipcode that exist
>   in the user table then it will be inserted other register from the
>   other supermarkets (with the lower price). The stock will be checked
>   everytime

Take a look at this:

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06df23c)

This is an example(i cannot upload images yet):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayvYW.jpg)

I have been trying so many times without success.I used min function in order to obtain the lower price:, ie:

```
SELECT idProduct
FROM product
WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM product);
```

Then,i tried  to use **not exist** function in order to solve this but i failed.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Hi @Stundent_new please can you provide a expected result ? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @VBokšić thank you very much for replying. I have attached an image within an example. Is that enough?

Comment: This one: "This is an example(i cannot upload images yet):" image ?

Comment: @VBokšić yes, the image is not shown in the thread itself

Comment: Ok, but that is the image showing table relations. And also you have given us some data in your SQL fiddle which is great. So now it would be great to show us what you expect to get as a result from that data? Because your query seems little bit too simple for what you are explaining you want to get.

Comment: Just at a glance, I'm guessing this type of sql puzzle is probably easier to solve in MySql 8, since 5.* doesn't have the window functions yet.

Comment: @VBokšić Basically, the user will have a form that will allow him to insert some data inside LIST table. He will only see product description from Products table and he will be able to insert the desired amount. The idea is to get only the items with the lowest price whose supermarket have the same zipcode.  I tried many queries but no one really helped me :/.I am not an expert :(

Comment: Ok, but when we give you the query code then you will expect to see some data that this query returns right ? (Like for example your query will return number 14)

Comment: @VBokšić This is an example: i want to insert 3 different items inside LIST table and then trigger some query to obtain the lowest price for each item (validating if the zipcode matches the one that is stored in user table and of course the stock available). This is an exercise, i am practicing SQL and i got stuck on this one :(